# How to simulate onPress event inside a function for redux connected component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, jestjs

How to simulate the onPress event using jest inside TouchableOpacity which is wrapped inside a function?
    I tried by mocking the onpress event inside the component 
    Issue came like
     Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

```
 it('should call _renderItem', () => {
      const mockFunc = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = shallow(
        <test onPress={mockFunc} navigation={navigation} store={store} />)
      wrapper.dive().find('TouchableOpacity').simulate('press');
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```

```
   class test extends PureComponent{

    renderlists(data){
    const press = () => {

      }
       return(
           <Fragment>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress = {press}> //simulate this onpress event
                 {data.list}
              </TouchableOpacity>
           </Fragment>
             )
    }

    render(){
    return(
    <FlatList
         data = {this.state.data}
         renderItem={this.renderlists}
    />
    )}
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        let { Reducer} = state;
        return {
            Reducer
        }
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(test );
```

```
 i tried like that its throwing issue like

Issue : Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `TouchableOpacity` into your test file and then:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent />).find(TouchableOpacity);
wrapper.simulate('press');
```

Comment: Are you sure there is any data in the this.state.data? @Praveenkumar